# Google Speech API request exceeds limit R

Tags: r, google-speech-api

I am receiving the following error when I am using the speech API. I am looking to have the same return as if a file would be under that limit. Thanks in advance.

```
asynch <- gl_speech(MonoPath,
                asynch = TRUE)
gl_speech_op(asynch)
Error: API returned: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.
```

Comment: Pay for access to the API?

Comment: I have access to the API, and have my CC linked up to it

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue and it appears it is because I have the API set on the free trial even though I have a CC connected to it.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas

by updating your account to a paid account you can increase your quotas.

I have yet to get approval to go paid from my finance department so I can't guarantee this will solve your issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the trial setting you  mentioned. You have to look at quotas for project and there will be a blue button indicating "Upgrade Account".

I did the upgrade but no change still getting the error
Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.

Using the Cloud SDK for Speech recognition and sending the request via the command line for a long running recognize command. No syntax errors other than a change to the example they gave was needed

Example, had to remove the single quotes around the file name and don't have spaces in your filename

```
gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running \
    'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac' \
     --language-code='en-US' --async
```

I seemed to be logged in properly, is it possible it is not recognizing my credentials properly and defaulting to trial type of request?

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?